# Post image in PHP Curl

Tags: javascript, php, curl, linkedin-api

I am trying to post image file as a param to my linkedIn wall using PHP CURL, but the image is not the one I am trying to post on linkedIn. I have tried with this below code:

```
 $linkedinShareOptions = array( 
                              'comment' => 'message',   
                              'content' => array(
                                               'title'  => 'TITLE',
                                               'description'  => 'hello world', 
                                               'submitted-url'  => $redirectUrl, 
                                               'submitted-image-url' => $imageSavedUrl
                                               ), 
                              'visibility'=> array('code' => 'anyone') 
                             );

 $linkedinShareOptions = json_encode($linkedinShareOptions);
 curl_setopt_array( $curl, array( 
                                  CURLOPT_URL            => CURL_OPT_URL,
                                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                                  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "POST",
                                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                                  CURLOPT_POST           => true,
                                  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
                                                                'x-li-format: json',
                                                                'Content-Type: application/json'
                                                                ),
                                  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $linkedinShareOptions
                                )
                  );
 $jsonResponseString = curl_exec( $curl );
 $httpResponseCode = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
 curl_close( $curl );

 $linkedinResponse = json_decode( $jsonResponseString );
```

The image which I wanted to post is saved in server and the same URL given for submitted-image-url but after successfull post, showing another image.

Please help me out from this issue.

Comment: What do you mean with "another" image? A random image from your server?

Comment: home page screen shot  of my website is taking